# Device Driver code compilation?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am new to linux .i have to compile a device driver sample code.

i tried to install linux-source-2.6.38 from the synaptic, then it showed the message quoted below:

> This package provides the source code for the Linux kernel version
>    2.6.38.
>
> This package is mainly meant for other packages to use, in order to build
>   custom flavours.
>
> If you wish to use this package to create a custom Linux kernel, then it
>   is suggested that you investigate the package kernel-package, which has
>   been designed to ease the task of creating kernel image packages.
>
> If you are simply trying to build third-party modules for your kernel,
>   you do not want this package. Install the appropriate linux-headers
>   package instead.

So get confused that:

1) a linux-source needed or not for my device driver code compilation ?

2) if i install the new kernel how can i work with the new kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need packages like `linux-headers-2.6-amd64` and `linux-kbuild-2.6`. Use `apt-cache search linux headers` and `apt-cache search linux kbuild` to find exactly the name of the packages.

You could use `apt-cache search linux headers` and  `apt-cache search linux kbuild` to get the exact name of the package.

If you are making a module (a dynamically loadable kernel module `*.ko`) you don't need to build a new kernel. Use `insmod` or `modprobe` to load it.

Answer (score 1):

for your first question, source code is not required for compiling your kernel modules and 
make sure that while inserting your module you must have root privilege

and for your second question if you want to compile the source code refer any kernel compilation links like http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html